Sql migration for data type change
I have encountered occasion where I have to change database column 'price' 's data type from string to decimal. Problem is in the database there are some incorrect existing values like '120.45.32' this shold corrected into '12045.32'. I have tried, CAST to decimal but it gives '120.00'. How can I resolve this in the migration file?
I have tried CAST(price as DECIMAL (10,2)). Migration works but all existing decimal values replace to '.00' like 120.45 -> 120.00

I don't think there's anything that will fix this automatically. You need to clean up the strings first, then you can cast them.

"On two occasions I have been asked, 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question." — Charles Babbage, 1864

Like Barmar said, you need to remove all first dots.
CREATE TABLE Vale (text_1 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Vale VALUES ('120.45.32')


SELECT * FROM Vale




text_1




120.45.32



UPDATE Vale 
SET text_1 = regexp_replace(text_1,'[\.]','',1,1)
WHERE    LENGTH(text_1)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( text_1, ".", '') )  = 2;
SELECT * FROM Vale


Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0





text_1




12045.32



fiddle

first Clean up the incorrect data
then Convert to a DECIMAL type

"First cleanup the incorrect data" ... that is literally the request of the OP .. the HOW to do that is the question.
